# Mention username in a Discord Modal of the person who opened it

Tags: discord.py

I'm currently experimenting with Discord Modals, and I was wondering if it was possible to mention the user in the modal of the person who opened it.

I want the first question in the modal to ask, **"Hey {user who opened the modal}, how do you like the server so far?"** I thought of adding that feature by adding the line `{ctx.author}`, however, since modals stem from a class type, that was not possible.

So, instead, I tried initializing a function that could take that context into the modal. Like this:

```py
#MODAL
class Feedback(discord.ui.Modal, title='Feedback'):
    def __init__(self, ctx: commands.Context):
        self.ctx = ctx

    def get_name(self):
        self.ctx.author
    
    feedback_text = discord.ui.TextInput(
        label=f'Hey {self.ctx.author}, how do you like the server so far?',
        placeholder='Feedback here...'
    )

    feedback = discord.ui.TextInput(
        label='What do you think of this new feature?',
        style=discord.TextStyle.long,
        placeholder='Type your feedback here...',
        required=False,
        max_length=300,
    )
```

I tried doing that but instead got an error message saying:

```
NameError: name 'self' is not defined
```

I'm not sure how else to make it work. Does someone have any ideas?

Comment: Place the code for the `TextInput`s in `__init__`, where `self` and `ctx` are defined

Comment: Could you show an example of what you mean @TheFungusAmongUs ? I tried doing what you mentioned but couldn't get it to work.